# Query Syntax help!

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am running this query in Access 2007 and getting a syntax error on this query

```
UPDATE INQuery SET Awords=(SELECT Coalsce("SELECT (parentdesc & '/' & keyword) From Awords     LEFT JOIN INQuery ON Awords.id=INQuery.item_id",";")) 
WHERE Awords.id=IN_Query.item_id;
```

> System error in query expression
>   '(SELECT Coalsce("SELECT (parentdesc &
>   '/' & keyword) From Awords LEFT JOIN
>   INQuery ON
>   Awords.id=INQuery.item_id",";"))'.

When I run the query expression separately I get the desired result.

> NOTE: To see what Coalsce function is
>   please refer 
>   [VBA + String splitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804273/vba-string-splitting)

Comment: Do you actually need the SELECT? `UPDATE INQuery SET Awords=Coalsce(...) WHERE ...`

Comment: @Jaymz, perfect, you are right, worked fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you actually need the additional `SELECT`?

```
UPDATE INQuery SET Awords=Coalsce(...) WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that it's `Coalesce` not `Coalsce`?  (typo?)

Comment: Its a function that I have written, so it shouldn't matter. The link I have provided is to another query where I have pasted the code for the function

Comment: Oh, I see.  You're not using the SQL `Coalesce` function here, but one you have written.  Unless you've changed it, you're missing a third parameter that contains a `Variant`.

Comment: Access does not support Coalesce, 2nd is that when I run the inner query separately, I get the results I need, so nothing wrong with that.